# Need help getting favicon working in browser C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, favicon

I have been trying to get favicon working on the Web browser that I am creating. I assume that I have to use an image and apply code to it. I found this code but `FromStream` and `FromFile` are giving me the error `System.Windows.Controls.Image` does not contain a definition for `FromStream` for both, as I am fairly new to programming I do not know what I need to do to solve the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code:

```
public static Image favicon(String u, string file)
{
   Uri url = new Uri(u);
   String iconurl = "http://" + url.Host + "/favicon.ico";

   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(iconurl);
   try
   {
       WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

       Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
       return Image.FromStream(s);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       //return a default icon in case 
       //the web site doesn`t have a favicon
       return Image.FromFile(file);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just change to `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream`

Answer (score 1):

I went through your code.

You need to use `Image` from `System.Drawing` namespace by referencing `System.Drawing.dll`.

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s)
```

`System.Windows.Controls.Image` does not have `FromFile` and `FromStream` methods.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess It might have helped somewhat, I am now getting the error "The type or namespace name 'Image' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" do I need to set Image to something somehow?

Comment: I can't comment on the content of this answer, but to use the `System.Drawing.Image` class, you'd need to add a reference to the `System.Drawing` dll.